# watch command smallest -n interval

Tags: watch

What is the smallest interval for the watch command?

The man page and Google searches do not indicate what the smallest interval lower limit is.  I found through experimentation it can be smaller than 1 second.

To test, I ran this command run on a firewall:

```
watch -n 0.1 cat /sys/class/net/eth1/statistics/rx_bytes
```

It clearly updates faster than one second, but it is not clear if it is really doing 100ms updates.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What platform are you on?

On my Linux (Ubuntu 14.10) the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/watch.1.html) says:

```
 -n, --interval seconds
          Specify  update  interval. The  command will not allow quicker
          than 0.1 second interval, in which the smaller values  are  con‐
          verted.
```

I just tested this with a script calling a C-program that prints the timestamp with microseconds and it works.

Comment: Platform is CentOS 6.6.  Man page states:  "[-n <seconds>]  By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use -n or --interval to specify a different interval." It doesn't specify what the lowest interval is.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 17):

`watch` command is included in [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/download.html) utilities.

The smallest value for `-n` option is `0.1`, it's hardcoded in [watch source (see line 171 - 172)](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/watch.c?view=markup):

```
case 'n':
    {
        char *str;
        interval = strtod(optarg, &str);
        if (!*optarg || *str)
            do_usage();
        if(interval < 0.1)
            interval = 0.1;
        if(interval > ~0u/1000000)
            interval = ~0u/1000000;
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 16):

Actually, you're at the limit. The man page *does* provide a minimal value (at least on my 2009, Linux version). Here it goes:

```
-n, --interval seconds
Specify update interval. The command will not allow quicker 
than 0.1 second interval, in which the smaller values are converted.
```

You can probably check that by using `date` through `watch`:

```
$ watch -n0.1 date +'%H:%M:%S:%N'
```

If you have a look at the first digit in the last field (nanoseconds), you'll see it quickly increments, meaning that for every `watch` iteration, ~100ms are added.

Comment: If you add a `-p` flag to your `date` example, then watch will try more carefully to be precise, and it will be very easy to judge from the second digit that this is indeed happening roughly every 100 ms.